# Update to Drupal Core 7.34 and the Password Fields are missing

Tags: entities, users

Update to Drupal Core 7.34 and the Password fields are missing in the user registration are no longer appearing.

Can't understand why. In the code they simply aren't being rendered.

site: http://kickstart.actliveonline.org/user/register

Comment: Are you referring to Drupal 7.34?

Comment: Yep sorry I mean Drupal 7.34

Comment: What happens when you remove password policy?

Comment: Well I found out that a long time ago I had messed around with the CSS and hide the password fields on the test site. So this is completely unrelated to updating Drupal.